# Jenkins is not able to authenticate Gitlab repository

Tags: jenkins, ssh, gitlab

I am trying to integrate Jenkins with Gitlab.
1) Jenkins is in my private IP server.
2) I have generated the SSH key from the Gitbash and created a folder '.ssh' and pasted in the Jenkins directory.
3) give correct SSH path in Jenkins and also credentials.
4)have all the plugins.

Problem:
Jenkins is not able to authenticate Gitlab repository.

**Error**

```
Started by user jenkinadmin
Building in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Hello World GitLab
 > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe config remote.origin.url git@gitlab.com:dhananjaymaurya/TAA_POC.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from git@gitlab.com:dhananjaymaurya/TAA_POC.git
 > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe --version # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
 > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe fetch --tags --progress git@gitlab.com:dhananjaymaurya/TAA_POC.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from git@gitlab.com:dhananjaymaurya/TAA_POC.git
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:797)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1051)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1082)
    at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:495)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1278)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:604)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:529)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1720)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:404)
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe fetch --tags --progress git@gitlab.com:dhananjaymaurya/TAA_POC.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

```
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1752)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1495)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$300(CliGitAPIImpl.java:64)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:315)
at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:795)
... 11 more
```

ERROR: null
Finished: FAILURE`

Comment: add logs, error messages that will help people understand what is failing.

Comment: I have added the error in the question now.